# GCP ComposerV2 missing log files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

We deployed GCP ComposerV2 with the most recent airflow version. It works perfectly. But from time to time "airflow_monitoring" predefined DAG crashes.

Here are the logs of the issue:

```
*** Log file is not found: gs://********/logs/airflow_monitoring/echo/2021-12-14T12:36:55+00:00/1.log. The task might not have been executed or worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g. was evicted)
*** 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/********/o/logs%2Fairflow_monitoring%2Fecho%2F2021-12-14T12%3A36%3A55%2B00%3A00%2F1.log?alt=media: No such object: ********/logs/airflow_monitoring/echo/2021-12-14T12:36:55+00:00/1.log: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

We don't change anything, this issue has happened randomly.

Here is the code of "airflow_monitoring" predefined DAG:

```
"""A liveness prober dag for monitoring composer.googleapis.com/environment/healthy."""
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
'airflow_monitoring',
default_args=default_args,
description='liveness monitoring dag',
schedule_interval=None,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))

# priority_weight has type int in Airflow DB, uses the maximum.
t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='echo',
bash_command='echo test',
dag=dag,
depends_on_past=False,
priority_weight=2**31-1)
```

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue after setting the retries to 2 or a higher number?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My retry is set to 3 but when this happens airflow does not attempt to run the task again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the log says everything:

```
*** Log file is not found: gs://********/logs/airflow_monitoring/echo/2021-12-14T12:36:55+00:00/1.log. The task might not have been executed or worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g. was evicted)
```

Kubernetes environment might from time to time evict a running task (for example when it fails over to another node because disk crashed or because the machines need to be restarted.

I think you should set retry to 2 and it should automatically retry in such case.